# Django model relations - "Owning" a related model enforced at the model level

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm not really sure how to title this question, so forgive my title's ambiguity.

I have two models, `Customer` and `Address`. Each has typical fields you would infer from their model names. `Address` is also set as an inline to `Customer` in admin.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_additional = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(choices=US_STATES)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street
```

I want to add a `billing_address` and `shipping_address` to the `Customer` model to allow a customer to choose one of several saved addresses to be used as those types of addresses accordingly, but I don't want any customer to be able to choose any address. My initial plan was to model the `Customer` with a foreign key relation back to `Address` while using `limit_choices_to` such as:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    billing_address = models.ForeignKey("Address", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='billing_address', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'customer_id':some_callable())
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey("Address", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='shipping_address', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'customer_id':some_callable())

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

I realized this is not how `limit_choices_to` is intended to work as there's no way to get a reference to `id` before the model is instantiated, and there's also no way to reference a property of `Address` in the value for `limit_choices_to` (this seems like a missing feature to me). I've seen other related questions that modify the admin form to enforce this, but I would much prefer to have this enforced at the model level.

**How should I model both `Customer` and `Address` so that a customer can have many addresses accessible only to them, and be able to choose one for each of `billing_address` and `shipping_address`?**

Answer (score 1):

1. The issue with using `limit_choices_to` is that it attempts to filter choices based on the customer_id attribute of the related model (Address).

However, it isn't aware of the specific customer instance for which this ForeignKey field is being used. Consequently, it doesn't have access to the customer instance being created, making it impossible to dynamically filter choices based on the specific customer instance's attributes.

You can use limit_choices_to to limit choices based on static criteria, such as the type (e.g., limiting choices to addresses with the type "home").

2. If you know you'll only ever need two addresses for each customer and won't require customization later, you can link Address to Customer like this:

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    # Fields for Customer model...
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey("Address", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey("Address", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

With this setup, you can assign an Address object to a Customer when defining the Customer or later on. You can even use one address for both billing and shipping:

```py
billing_address = Address(street=..., ...)
new_customer = Customer(..., billing_address=billing_address, shipping_address=billing_address)
```

Or you can assign addresses when declaring the Customer:

```py
Customer(..., billing_address=Address(street=..., ...), shipping_address=Address(street=..., ...))
```

Find addresses not linked to any customer

```py
unlinked_addresses = Address.objects.filter(customer__isnull=True)
```

Get all addresses for the customer

```py
address = customer.address_set.filter()
```

or access directly

```py
customer.shipping_address
customer.billing_address
```

3. However, if you need to allow customers to define multiple addresses, it's advisable to link Customer to Address as follows:

```py
class AddressType(models.IntegerChoices):
    BILLING = 1, _("Billing address")
    SHIPPING = 2, _("Shipping address")

class Customer(models.Model):
    # Fields for Customer model...

class Address(models.Model):
    # Fields for Address model...
    address_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=AddressType.choices)
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_address_type",
                fields=["customer", "address_type"],
            )
        ]
```

Side note: Be cautious about using the keyword "zip" since it's reserved for Python syntax.

Comment: This is okay but still a bit clunky, as it needs the same address entered twice for it to be both the shipping and billing address. Also just a side note, this is not for an e-commerce site. This is for a brick and mortar point of sale application.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is that two customers might share an address (housemates? people in a business?) as well as one customer having multiple addresses.  So it's not a `ForeignKey` relationship, but a `ManyToMany` relationship.

There's quite a steep learning curve associated with these, but it has to be climbed because that's what the data says! And it provides a large part of the solution at the forms level (also Django admin), because every address will have a `customer_set`, and every customer will have an `address_set`.